# Does Spring PROPAGATION_REQUIRED on a method block other threads?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

Say a thread enters a method called m1() and starts a new transaction. When second thread tries to enter the same method, we are noticing that the second method is being blocked. Does PROPOGATION_REQUIRED block the second thread until the first thread has completed the job? Isolation is NOT set(default).

Thanks.

Comment: What's the size of your connection pool? The other thread may block trying to acquire its database connection.

Comment: The connection pool have been set liberally. Still see that there are a lot of connection that are free

Comment: Have a look what the thread is waiting for then - jconsole can help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the transaction propagation settings have nothing to do with one thread being blocked. Transactions are precisely used to allow several threads to access the same database concurrently without problems.

Is this method synchronized? Because that would explain the blocking behavior.

Comment: Verified that the method is not synchronized. Thanks.

Comment: You could also have an interceptor in the AOP stack that synchronizes the calls.